# how to store git personal authentication token (PAT) in Arch linux using command line

Tags: git, github

I'm facing issue to store the PAT token in my arch linux pc , for git to automatically fill them when I push my code .
I've tried the commands

- git config --global commit.gpgsign false
- git config --global credential.helper etc.

please help

Comment: What exactly was the command about `git config --global credential.helper` and in what way it didnt't help?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question , I think it was about git-credential-helper tool . But it doesn't matter I found the solution to my problem . I accidentally run some wrong git config command and because of that the correct command which is 
- git config --global credential.helper store 
didn't work earlier .
Today I cleared my git config file and re run this command and entered my username and PAT in place of password and it stored it and didn't ask for it the next time.

Answer (score 1):

The command for git to configure it to store the PAT is -

`git config --global credential.helper store`

my command line was showing error because I accidentally run a wrong git config command which was causing the error
so I had to clear all the unnecessary configs from my git config file by using the following command

`git config --global --edit`

and then delete all the unnecessary configs and run the

`git config --global credential.helper store`

command to store my username and PAT the next time git asks me for it
It worked , I entered it one time and the next time it didn't ask me for the credentials , it just used the stored ones.